# MySQL update multiple rows multiple values from other table giving duplicate values

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a simple query as like below

```
UPDATE tablea, 
       tableb 
SET    tablea.id = tableb.id 
WHERE  tablea.phone1 = tableb.phone2
```

I get unexpected results after update. Please refer to http://hastebin.com/opibutixow.1c

**leads in vicidial_list table with phone numbers that are in custom_1026 table:**

```
SELECT lead_id 
FROM   vicidial_list 
WHERE  phone_number IN (SELECT fos_mobile 
                        FROM   custom_1026); 
+---------+
| lead_id |
+---------+
|   79498 |
|   79499 |
|   79500 |
|   79497 |
|   79496 |
|   79495 |
|   79494 |
|   79493 |
|   79492 |
|   79491 |
|   79490 |
+---------+
```

**leads in custom_1026 after update command resulting duplicates**

```
UPDATE custom_1026 
       INNER JOIN vicidial_list 
               ON ( custom_1026.fos_mobile = vicidial_list.phone_number ) 
SET    custom_1026.lead_id = vicidial_list.lead_id; 

SELECT lead_id FROM custom_1026;

+---------+
| lead_id |
+---------+
|   79500 |
|   79499 |
|   79492 |
|   79493 |
|   79495 |
|   79495 |
|   79498 |
|   79498 |
|   79498 |
|   79491 |
|   79491 |
+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
UPDATE tablea a
JOIN   tableb b
  ON   a.phone1 = b.phone2 
SET    a.id = b.id
```

But i think you are asking the wrong question.

Try to check if your data is correct first, probably you have duplicate phone numbers.

```
SELECT phone_number , count(*)
FROM vicidial_list 
GROUP BY phone_number 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

and

```
SELECT fos_mobile, count(*)
FROM custom_1026
GROUP BY fos_mobile 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I am sure there are no duplicates I can show you the results table once I get server access.

Comment: I have edited the question  i will run your suggested queries & provide results shortly

Comment: You are right phone is not unique what I need is to get all inserted ids in vicidial_list of previous transaction & update to custom_1026 table. Is there a better way to handle this cases, probably what I may need to solve is to get last inserted id and increment by 1 till the count is reached & then insert to custom_1026 table